# MPMusicPlayerController not play on background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

i am using MPMusicPlayerController in my app and when i enter to background it stop playing.

this is how i add it :

```
musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indicate in your app's plist file that you want to play audio in the background.

Answer (score 5):

The `iPodMusicPlayer` is always enabled in the background. You shouldn't have to set anything. And `[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer]` won't play in the background ever. I'd say you're using the wrong `MPMusicPlayerController` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you create the applicationMusicPlayer it is not play in back ground.
you have to create ipodMusicPlayer to overcome this.

check this out for further refference.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008221